# Ruby regex that match all tags except script tag

Tags: regex, ruby

For example i have string:

```
content = "<h1>test</h1>\n<script>$(function(){alert('test')});</script>\n<b>bold</b>"

content.scan(/>.*?</m) # should not get the script tag content
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't fully follow what you are trying to do here, but in any case, please don't use regex to parse HTML, use a proper XML parser instead (and Ruby must have support for this).

Comment: Important in the context of parsing HTML with regexp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
"<h1>test</h1>\n<script>$(function(){alert('test')});</script>\n<b>bold</b>".
  scan(/>[^<]*?<(?!\/script>)/)
#⇒ [">test<", ">\n<", ">\n<", ">bold<"]
```

Comment: Hi @Aleksei i tried you answer here  https://rubular.com/r/hX0Mc8ZKLzGhVm

Comment: You were asking about ruby and I posted the ruby answer. I have corrected it to return a proper result on your website as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i need :) i just need escape \< (first occurrence)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Ruby supports PCRE, if so you can use regex verbs like this:

```
<\/?script>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<\/?\w+>
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EkKzTp/1)**

In case you cannot use verbs (skip and fail), then you can use the discard technique like this:

```
<\/?script>|(<\/?\w+>)
```

And then access to the capturing group and grab the content of the matched tag